# CSS How to keep page centered, but still put stuff where I want

Tags: html, css

Absolute positioning is great, but it seems to position it relative to the browser window.  This doesn't work for me because the content of my page is centered.  I trying to build a structure similar to [Allegorithmic](http://www.allegorithmic.com/).  Notice as the bottom left of the page there is a grey bar with a section entitled "About", then to the right of that "Quick Links" and "Stay Connected".  So if I have that grey bar section centered in the page - how do I position those three sections as they are? (one to the right of the other).  Again, all I can think to do is absolute position them where I want them to be, but isn't there a way of "absolute" positioning things within their respective div tags instead of the main window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to position your container relatively.

This will ensure that absolutely positioned items are relative to your container.

```
#container{
  position:relative;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AYc7A/)

Comment: With this new knowledge, I can position my stuff anywhere! Is it best practice to use relative containers and absolute positioning for sub content?

Comment: Yeah. You generally want your content positioned relative to some container. Sometimes you want it relative to the document.

Answer (score 0):

When you position an HTML element using CSS, it is positioned *relative* to the closest parent element which is positioned. For example:

```
<div id="A" style="height:100px; width:400px; margin: 10px auto;">
  <div id="a" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
    <p id="a">Hello World!</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

In the above example, `<div id="a" ...>` will be positioned relative to the browser window, at absolute offset `top: 10px` and `left: 10px`, **relative to the browser window**.

```
<div id="B" style="position: relative; height:100px; width:400px; margin: 10px auto;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px;">
    <p id="b">Hello World!</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

In this example, `<div id="a" ...>` will be positioned relative to `<div id="B" ...>` (at the same absolute offsets, but this time **relative to `<div id="B">`**. This is because in the second example, `<div id="B">` has a `position` CSS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look for relative positioning (you should then set the width of parent div and relative position for buttons inside).

You also could do that (maybe better):

```
<div id="footer">
   <div class="element">...</div>
   <div class="element">...</div>
   <div class="element">...</div>
</div>
```

with css for footer centering it and for element:

```
div.element{
   float:left;
   //... Rest of style
}
```

Edit:
   You could also use javascript to do positioning. But it is only my redundant idea - you could achieve this with css only.